# ENC28J60 Circuit Connected With 2 Magjack in Parallel

Tags: circuit-analysis, ethernet, rj45, tcp-ip, enc28j60

I'm using ethernet controller chip ENC28J60 and I need to have it connected to 2 magjack in parallel, but I'm unsure if I made a correct circuit, is this can work?

Please advise me, thank you very much..

[image]

Comment: why do you need parallel jacks? ... there is no way to know if the circuit is correct because you said nothing about the circuit's purpose ... my first guess is that the circuit is completely useless

Comment: If this works at all (unlikely) are you aware that you won't be able to use both at the same time?

Comment: Two transformers will violate Ethernet spec. the transmission lines will have the wrong loading, which will make it so you can't depend on distances or speed of the either spec. You'll need to phys

Comment: It might be possible to find a transceiver buffer